# Intercom : iOS App crashing on updating user only on iOS 10.3.2

Tags: ios, swift, intercom-ios

We have few iOS users for whom app is crashing while updating user on Intercom. All are having iOS 10.3.2.

This is how we update user on Intercom after registration

```
registerIntercomUser(userNo: self.gbl.getUserNo())

_ = dispatch_after(1) {

updateIntercomUser(userObj: userObj!, userNo:self.gbl.getUserNo())

}
```

below is the log we get on crashlytics

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Evolution                      0x100061b84 specialized     updateIntercomUser(userObj : User, userNo : Int) -> ()     (IntercomLogger.swift:1543)
1  Evolution                      0x1000d97e4 partial apply for      ViewController.(checkLogin() -> ()).(closure #1) (ViewController.swift)
2  Evolution                      0x100148b28 partial apply for  (dispatch_after(Double, queue : DispatchQueue, closure : () -> ()) -> () ->  ()?).(closure #2) (Util.swift)
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fce9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fdb604 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 448
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fe7c1c _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fd08a0 _dispatch_source_invoke + 804
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fd34a0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 668
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1920c50c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1920c2ce4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
10 CoreFoundation                 0x191ff2da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific +  424
11 GraphicsServices               0x193a5c074 GSEventRunModal + 100
12 UIKit                          0x1982ad058 UIApplicationMain + 208
13 Evolution                      0x10005ea28 main (IntercomLogger.swift:17)
14 libdyld.dylib                  0x19100159c start + 4
```

Please help e find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

crash was due to calling updateuser method of intercom on main thread. Putting all calls on background thread fixed the crash.